# Bitbucket связать с хостом

Tags: репозиторий, хостинг

Создал репозиторий на Bitbucket, и есть некий обычный хостинг с поддержкой php. Как можно настроить так, чтобы при залитии в bitbucket все изменения отправлялись на сервер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбирайте свой проект, жмите шестеренку, слева в меню hooks, выбирайте POST, вводите url,  там где-то ещё есть дока по параметрам, можете ее читать, а можете просто тестовое изменение сделать и залогировать этот POST. И на основании полученных данных делайте checkout/pull.

Comment: спасибо :) с хуком уже немного побаловался :) и вроде что-то получилось :)